# Characterization of weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $*$ be the convolution product and $\eta_n$, $\eta$ be random variables to $\mathbb{R}$ then we have:
$$ \eta_n \mbox{ converges weakly to } \eta \Leftrightarrow \mbox{ for every contuously distributed } \varepsilon \mbox{ we have: }\\ (F_{\eta_n} * F_{\varepsilon})_n \mbox{ converges uniformly to }  (F_{\eta} * F_{\varepsilon})$$
where $F_{\eta}$ is the cumulative distribution function of $\eta$. I would like to prove this statement or get a reference for a proof. What would be even more more awesome if this had a generalization for filters.

Comment: This seems like it should be pretty straightforward to prove.  What have you tried?  Skorohod's representation theorem might be convenient.  Also, since the topology of weak convergence of $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables is metrizable (look up the Levy metric, for instance), the statement for filters follows immediately from that for sequences.

Comment: I had just tried to prove it directly without using any statements, I'm not used to working with convolution products.

I didn't know that weak convergence of $\mathbb{R}$ valued random variables is metrizable (I even thought that it wasn't since it isn't metrizable in general), so thanks for that information! I'll try to prove it again using your theorem tomorrow, can I put some kind of "hold" on my question, since I'd like to try to prove it with your hints.

Comment: There isn't really a way to "hold".  If you want, you can delete the question and undelete it later.  Or you can just leave it.

Comment: I'll delete it ;)! Well thx for the response :)

Comment: So I almost got it, the direction $\Rightarrow$ is clear now, for $\Leftarrow$ I have used $\varepsilon_m$ as the uniform distribution on $[-1/m,1/m]$ using this I proved that for each $m$ we have:

$$ \frac{m}{2} \int_{-1/m}^{1/m} F_n(t-x) dx \rightarrow \frac{m}{2} \int_{-1/m}^{1/m} F(t-x) dx $$
where the right hand side is about the same as $F(t)$ if $F$ is contuous at $t$ so the only thing left to prove is that $ (\frac{m}{2} \int_{-1/m}^{1/m} F_n(t-x) dx)_n$ is equivalent to $(F_n(t))_n$.

Comment: Why do the $F_n$ converge uniformly to a uniformly continuous function?

Comment: Oh sorry, never mind.